# How to precheck some checkbox in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, checklistbox

My code has many atributes that have to be choosed by user, he can choose 0 or all and sometimes some atributes will come checked if this user has been choose the atributes before, i've try hard to do this with reactjs but `checked` and `defaultChecked` props are confuse to me, here my code sample.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    colors: [ 'red', 'black', 'green', 'blue', 'white', 'yellow' ],
    checkedColors: [ 'blue', 'yellow' ]
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const { target } = e
    const formData = new FormData(target)
    const checkedColors = formData.getAll('colors')
    this.setState({ checkedColors })
  }
  
  render() {
  const { colors, checkedColors } = this.state
  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
      <ul>
        {colors.map((color, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            <input
              type='checkbox'
              name='colors'
              id={color}
              value={color}
              checked={checkedColors.some(chckColor => chckColor === color)}
            />
            <label htmlFor={color}>{color}</label>
           </li>
         ))}
        </ul>
        <button>submit</button>
        <span>{checkedColors.join(', ')}</span>
       </form>
     )
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: blue and yellow are selected, where is the problem ?  you want to change them recheck and check

Comment: You probably want to assign `onChange` for every input and change `checkedColors` according to the new selection. This, in turn, will reflect in the updated checked state of the inputs. See https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components for more details.

Comment: @RenaldoBalaj yes i can see it, but i need to check more colors if i want

Comment: i gave a working demo at the answer,  comment there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5pdd5f  You have the working demo here :)

The checkbox needs 2 attributed:
**checked**: which is true or false (you can set default here too)

**onChange**: when someone removes the click or adds a click you must register it

*For questions comment below*

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by assigning a true boolean value to the checked attribute.

Sample code below:

```
checked={ yourCondition ? true : false }
```

If your condition is matched, the checkbox will be checked.